# Java - Get difference between old and new size of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

After I do a resizing at a JFrame, is there any method that returns the difference between the old and new size, i.e (dx,dy) ?

If not, is there a way to get this info?

[(dx,dy) - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNNmb.png)

Comment: *"..is there a way to get this info?"* Why? See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what the size was before the frame was resized, then you could use a `ComponentListener` to detect when the frame's size was changed. The trick here is knowning when the "size" has changed to a fixed point from which taking a measure is worthwhile.  Once the frame has "settled" you would simply need to calculate the difference from the "last resize" to now

Start by having a look at [How to Write a Component Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html)

Conceptually, you want to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999349/java-swing-repaint-dont-work-correctly/29000414#29000414) or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318051/width-and-height-of-a-jpanel-are-0-specific-situation/24318121#24318121)